# InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/static/media/index.c6592bb6.ts') is not a valid name

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react app that I am trying to convert to use typescript

but I'm getting the following error: `InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/static/media/index.c6592bb6.ts') is not a valid name.`

What does this error even mean? It looks like it doesn't like the typescript extension

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: We mostly can't help you with code we can't see. If the answer below isn't sufficient, you'll need to chip away at the problem until you have a [mcve] you can share that other scan use to replicate the problem so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 54):

In my case, I was building my web app and I had created a javaScript file in the IDE IntelliJ. But in the folder, the file name was missing the suffix ".js". So when I used 'npm run dev' command in the terminal, it failed to find the file I had created.

If it is the same for you, then just go to the folder and add the suffix ".js" in the file name.

I think it's a bug in IntelliJ, Hopefully they may fix it later on.

Comment: Thanks. (6 more to go...)

Comment: did the same with another IDE xD thank you!

Comment: Has the same problem with visual studio code and changing the file to .jsx also worked

Comment: same issue, named my file indexjs and couldnt figure out the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 40):

In my case, it was just importing asset like this

```js
import { ReactComponent as PaintIcon } from "./assets/paint.svg";
```

instead of

```js
import PaintIcon from "./assets/paint.svg";
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting the below error when I try the above approach. Any idea how to fix this?

./src/icons/exports.js 163:0-19Can't import the named export 'ReactComponent' (reexported as 'AddIcon') from default-exporting module (only default export is available)

Comment: Can't say anything without looking at the files

Answer (score 14):

There might be a dummy file in the name of index which not having ".js" as the suffix.

Or Your index file might not have ".js" suffix.

So rename it

Comment: +1 : As stupid as it sounds , I did create a component without .js suffix and was struggling with above issues for some time.

Answer (score 4):

The problem for me was that I was trying to render ts files. React can't 'create elements' from ts files. TS files need to be transpiled to JS. I thought that my babel loader was configured correctly but it wasn't. The babel loader wasn't checking for ts or tsx files.

Answer (score 3):

It means you have code trying to do this:

```
document.createElement("/static/media/index.c6592bb6.ts")
```

...directly or indirectly. Since `/static/media/index.c6592bb6.ts` isn't a valid tag name (like `div` or `span`), it fails.

Comment: but why did it work with .js? and how do you fix it?

Comment: @RedBaron - It doesn't. You fix it by not doing that. :-)

Comment: I have fixed it (I think) but now im getting a weird error `Parsing error: Unexpected token interface`. the syntax is definitely correct. `export interface IContainerProps {prop: any}` and it's in a `.tsx` file but for some reason it's blowing up :/

Comment: I faced similar issue. It worked fine my laptop, then I uploaded it on github. Once, Uploading finished, I downloaded those files from github, and now I am getting similar issue mentioned above,

Answer (score 3):

I got this error also and I don't see it described in the solutions was a mistake on my part of having quotes as part of my Route component assignment.

```
<Route component="{ NotFound }" />
```

Removing the quotes solved the issue.

```
<Route component={ NotFound } />
```

Answer (score 3):

in my case i was importing SVG like:

```
import SidebarButton from '../../assets/images/sidebarbutton.svg';
```

And just using that:

```
<SideBarButtonImg>
```

This fixed the issue:

```
const SideBarButtonImg = () => (
  <button style={{height: '100%'}}>
    <img
      src={sidebarbutton}
      alt=""
      style={{
        height: '100%',
        background: '#fff',
      }}
    />
  </button>
)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem relevant to the original intention, which is to import a SVG as a proper React component.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it hasn't been specified before, I had the same issue with Home document and it was because I used this:

```
<Route path="/" component="{Home}" />
```

Instead of this

```
<Route path="/" component={Home} />
```

Note the quote marks. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this using `@svgr/webpack` in my webpack config:

```
  { test: /\.svg$/, use: ['@svgr/webpack'] },
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this Helps but I had the same error message and it was flagging the following:

```
ReactDOM.render ( <App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

For me it was a simple mistake (as mentioned by someone already) of not having the file with correct extension. In my case it was SearchBox child that was saved as a text file and not as "SearchBox.js". In your case it would be the "Index" file. Granted I am completely new to this and am still learning, just thought I would share as reading previous responses to your question helped me fix my issue!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check that there is a file in your source folder or in public folder with no proper extension mean's like "

> index

" add a proper extension to it or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

haha, I have the same error and bothered me for a long time.

```
import GuessLikeList from './GuessLikeList/GuessLikeList.jsx';
```

and error

```
Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('./GuessLikeList/GuessLikeList.jsx') is not a valid name.
```

It means can not execute with '.jsx',so you have to change filename extension or import some modules to compile jsx

Answer (score 0):

I got this error. It happened that the name of the js folder had spaces at the end of it. Seems React doesn't recognise space in folder/file names.

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, I had the error in my App.js. The App.js had a wrong name on the route path like this  So I had to correct the path name and that fixed my error.

Answer (score -1):

make sure you added .js at the name of your file as well as when you import it