# Import .mdx file into React.jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mdx, mdxjs

I am trying to show .mdx files into a React application. My .dx file is

```
//Post.mdx

---
title: Example Document
author: Jane Smith
date: August 15, 2023
---

# Welcome to My Example Document

This is a demonstration of an `.mdx` document with stylized content. Here, we'll explore some formatting options.
```

My .jsx code:

```
import { MDXProvider } from "@mdx-js/react";
import Post from './Post.mdx';


const components = {
  em: props => <i {...props} />
}



const Introduction = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Sidebar />

      <div className="introduction">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="content">
          <MDXProvider components={components}>
            <Post />
          </MDXProvider>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Introduction;
```

But it give this error:

```
Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/static/media/Post.c270f98726682967eabb.mdx') is not a valid name.
```

How can I solve this issue and import .mdx file into React application? I am also open for new ideas.

Comment: What kind of build process do you have? Are you using CRA, webpack, rollup, vite?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54003685/invalidcharactererror-failed-to-execute-createelement-on-document-the-tag)

Comment: Please add you package.json. That should answer my question

Comment: Have you followed. [MDX's setup process for webpack](https://mdxjs.com/packages/loader/)?

Comment: Thanks for your help but it does not fully help.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your webpack config and package.json

Comment: @Zachiah I want to use storybook inside mdx file to create a documentation page. When I add the necessary things to the webpack.config.js file, I get ``Cannot read properties of null (reading 'referenceMeta') TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'referenceMeta') ```. I explained the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76914413/storybook-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-referencemeta-error). However, when I delete it, I cannot use the mdx file. I would be very thankful if you help me to solve this situation.